# Form Close Issue in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Login Form` that is checking roles on login time. If role is `Normal User` it is opening `Form1`. If role is `Register` then it's opening `Form2`. After opening `Form1` or `Form2` i am closing login form using `this.close`. When role is `Normal User` it's opening Form1 and Closing Login Form Perfectly while when role is `Register` it's closing both forms.

Here is the code.

```
if (ROLE != "Register")
{
    Form1 form1= new Form1();
    if (ROLE == "Normal User")
    {
        form1.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
    if (ROLE == "Bulk User")
    {
        form1.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
else
{
    Form2 form2= new Form2();
    form2.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

`Login Form` and `Form1` are WPF Forms While `Form2` is a Windows Form

Comment: Is it possible to change the design of this particular code? Its not a good practice to remove the parent form i.e. Login form before closing child forms. Handle the above logic (close of login form and show of form1 or form2 logic) outside the login form Best place would be parent of login form.

Comment: @MukulVarshney, you mean i must not close `Login Form` as long as my application is Running ?

Comment: I believe you should override the `OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)` in your Appl.xaml to start with the LoginForm.

Comment: @shadow, still same problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because second form gets disposed when parent form getting closed, You can do following

```
else
{
      Form2 form2 = new Form2();
      form2.Show();
      this.Hide();
      form2.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the same problem affect form1?

Comment: As he mentioned form 1 is wpf form and it works correct, That's why I suggested only for second form.

Comment: @GevorgNarimanyan, should i make form2 in WPF as well to work correctly ???

Comment: @محمدخرمشھزاد Yes it's a better solution if you have a time:)

Comment: @GevorgNarimanyan, Yeah got Solved after changing my Windows form to WPF Form